# Why are orthogonal projection matrices not ... orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projective-geometry, orthogonality

I know that given an orthogonal matrix U, then orthogonal projection onto the column space of U is represented by the matrix $UU^t$, which is again orthogonal.  I've computed these types of matrices many times now.

But when reading online sources such as Wolfram, they give examples of orthogonal projection matrices with a zero column or a zero row, and a couple of 1s - such as the well-known matrix that projects (x,y,z) to (x,y,0).

But this matrix doesn't even  have full rank, let alone be unitary or orthogonal.

Where's my conceptual mistake?

Thanks,

Comment: An orthogonal projection is not what is represented by an orthogonal matrix. It just orthogonally projects the space onto some subspace. Since subspaces have lower dimension, they cannot be full rank. An orthogonal matrix is a linear isometry of the (Euclidean) vector space you are looking at.

Comment: Ah, of course.  The mapping can't be onto, unless it's the trivial projection, $I_{nxn}$.  Thanks so much for your quick response, @Thomas :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem not to have noticed a few things about those calculations you say you've done many times. Given an orthogonal matrix $U$, in fact $UU^T$ is the *identity* matrix. So yes it is "again orthogonal", but that's a curious way to put it. And yes it is the projection onto the column space of $U$, because in fact that column space is all of $\Bbb R^n$.

On the other hand, if $P$ is the matrix that gives the orthogonal projection onto a proper subspace $V$ of $\Bbb R^n$ then $P$ cannot be orthogonal. An orthogonal matrix maps $\Bbb R^n$ onto itself, while $P$ maps $\Bbb R^n$ onto $V$. So the rank of $P$ should be the dimension of $V$, which is less than $n$.

Comment: Absolutely, Professor Ullrich.  I follow your answer; I certainly meant that I've done the non-trivial computations many times, e.g., starting with a 3x1 column vector U, normalize it, and getting a 3x3 matrix $UU^t$ that is projection onto a line.  I agree that I naively thought this $UU^t$ is orthogonal, which now I understand would be nonsensical.  It's not a surjective mapping.  Thanks so much @davidc.ullrich :-)

Answer (score 2):

Concept "orthogonal matrix" (inverse is transpose) vs concept "orthogonal projection" (self adjoint, idempotent).

Comment: Sorry, @mvw, that is not to say that *all* self-adjoint and real symmetric matrices represent orthogonal projection, right?  But rather: projection matrices are orthgonal i.f.f. they are self-adjoint (symmetric in real space).  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: I just listed the two properties idempotency (so it is a projection) and self-adjointness (so the projection is orthogonal), I left out that I considered linear maps only.